# Using $match in Moongose Aggretation Pipeline In Mongodb on a field of type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model called appointments that has a field called doctor which is of **type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,**. I am trying to perform an aggregation on the model and In the first stage i am doing a $match on doctor field to get only documents that match the supplied doctor id. the problem is that i get an empty array when i run the query yet the doctor id i am looking for is in the database. Below is my appoitment model. Now i do not understand why i am not able to get result when i do query on the hospital and doctor field yet if a do a match on the status field i get the data. Is it because the doctor and the hospital fields are of type  **type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId** .  Please help

```
const appointmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    patient: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: 'Patient user id must be provided'
    },
    hospital: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: 'Hopital is reqired'
    },
    doctor: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: 'Doctor is require'
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Active',
      trim: true,
      enum: {
        values: ['Active', 'Inactive'],
        message: 'Wrong Status Supplied'
      }
    },
    startDate: {
      type: Date,
      required: true
    },
    endDate: {
      type: Date
    },
    completed: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    message: String,
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now()
    }
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
  }
);
```

and below is my aggregation ppipeline

```
exports.doctorSchedlue = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {


  const aggregateData = await Appointment.aggregate([
    { $match: { doctor: '5ee9be0147faee607cb3cea8' } }
  ]);

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    id: req.params.id,
    aggregateData
  });
});
```

Comment: The [Mongoose - SchemaTypes - ObjectId](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids) maps to an [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/index.html). You are trying to comapre with a _string_.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

```
exports.doctorSchedlue = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const doctAppointments = await Appointment.find({ doctor: req.params.id });

  const aggregateData = await Appointment.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { doctor: new ObjectId('5ee9be0147faee607cb3cea8') }
    }
  ]);

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    id: req.params.id,
    aggregateData,
    doctAppointments
  });
});
```